# SSIS Outputting a File

Tags: ssis

[image]Here is the scenario:

1. I have headers in my data steam.
2. They are not actually part of
   the data, but actual headers.
3. I cannot get the headers to output through the flat file destination step.
4. I have the box unchecked for selecting the first record.[image: proof]

[image: Overview]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit #1: The headers are present in the source. When I use a data viewer in the step before the "flat file destination" step, they are there. For some reason, they are not being output.

Edit #2: I added the additional image.

Edit #3: I added an additional image. This is my settings for the Flat File Connection Manager Editor and it still is not giving me my headers.

[image]

Edit #4: Added Preview Image for Flat File Destination Step

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625064/export-sql-server-query-output-from-ssis-to-text-file-including-the-column-heade

Comment: Please elaborate. I didn't understand. You have header as row in SQL source and want same in Flatfile destination?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: @theDbGuy Thank you, I will check this out and get back with you.

Comment: @PrabhatG and and Tab Alleman, I have clarified my question

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I attached a 3rd image and still am not having any success.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to output Headers in destination the way they are present in source. Here is my input(notice header in first line):

[image: img1]

Next, make sure you untick this:
[image: img2]

That's it. Connect output and flow will bring headers to output file

Comment: I apologize but I am somewhat new to SSIS. I edited my original post and attached another image. That is not check marked and the headers that I am wanting to output are not in the source file at all. I aggregate some data and those become my new headers.